# $invalid not triggering in ionic angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do a required field validation in ionic / angularjs and it doesn't seem to be triggering  {{user.$invalid}} is not being set when I interact with the form.  New to angular and ionic, so what is the right way of doing required field validators in this case.

```
<form novalidate >
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.uname" required>

          <div class="error-container" ng-show="user.uname.$dirty && user.uname.$invalid">
            <small class="error" ng-show="user.uname.$error.required">Please input a uname</small>
          </div>
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="user.pwd" required>
          <div class="error-container" ng-show="user.pwd.$dirty && user.pwd.$invalid">
            <small class="error" ng-show="user.pwd.$error.required">Please input a password</small>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="item">
          <div lass="error-container">{{message}}</div>
           <div lass="error-container">Invalid:{{user.$invalid}}</div>
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-disabled="user.$invalid" ng-click="login(user)">Log in</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just forgot to name your form:

```
<form novalidate name="user">
```

Angular will only create $scope members for *named* forms and inputs.

From the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms:

> A form is an instance of FormController. The form instance can optionally be published into the scope using the name attribute.
>
> Similarly, an input control that has the ngModel directive holds an instance of NgModelController. Such a control instance can be published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute on the input control. The name attribute specifies the name of the property on the form instance.